# How to loop through parsed JSON array using jquery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following data which is being parsed and then I am looping through to attempt to get each state ID and name.

```
{
    "billing": {
        "ACT": "Australian Capital Territory",
        "NSW": "New South Wales",
        "NT": "Northern Territory",
        "QLD": "Queensland",
        "SA": "South Australia",
        "TAS": "Tasmania",
        "VIC": "Victoria",
        "WA": "Western Australia"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "ACT": "Australian Capital Territory",
        "NSW": "New South Wales",
        "NT": "Northern Territory",
        "QLD": "Queensland",
        "SA": "South Australia",
        "TAS": "Tasmania",
        "VIC": "Victoria",
        "WA": "Western Australia"
    }
}
```

```js
data = '{"billing":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"},"shipping":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"}}';

data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
billingData = data.billing;

$(billingData).each( function( key, value ) {
    console.log( key + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting the console to loop through each state ID and the label, but I get they key as 0 and the value as an object, I have also tried looping through the outputted object (contained in value from the original `.each`).

I have also tried looping through `billingData[0]`.

Comment: Use `$.each(billingData, fun...` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `jQuery.each()` instead of `.each()` to do this work.

The [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop through jquery elements but [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop through array or object.

```js
data = '{"billing":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"},"shipping":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"}}';

data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
billingData = data.billing;

$.each(billingData, function(key, value) {
 console.log(key +": "+ value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - that works! But why isn't what I am attempting to do the same result?

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge Because you trying to convert your json obj to jquery object (`$(billingData)`) and loop through it that isn't right.

Comment: Ahh! damn - okay great, will accept this as the answer when the time limit allows.

Answer (score 1):

`billingData` is not an array. It's an object.   jQuery `each` will let you iterate through an object as though it were an array, or you could just use object methods:

```js
data = '{"billing":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"},"shipping":{"ACT":"Australian Capital Territory","NSW":"New South Wales","NT":"Northern Territory","QLD":"Queensland","SA":"South Australia","TAS":"Tasmania","VIC":"Victoria","WA":"Western Australia"}}';

data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
billingData = data.billing;

Object.keys(billingData).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key + ": " + billingData[key])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of each:

$.each(array, function( key, value ) {

});

$('.element').each(function () {

});